# Should I scale targets when building regression model with multiple objects?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, data-preprocessing

I'm using `TensorFlow 2` to build a regression neural network with four numeric output objects. Each object has a distribution that is close to the normal distribution. The mean and variance of those distributions are different but close (For example, $Normal(0.2, 0.01)$ and $Normal(0.5, 0.04)$). I'm wondering should I scale the targets before training? Moreover, should I scale the targets if they have very different magnititudes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary. Neural networks don't need your target to be a standardized normal variable. Don't hesitate to share your results though!